# How to change URL from "foo.boo.edu/someone/someone.htm" to "foo.boo.edu/~someone"?

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to shorten the website of our research lab.

The 1st step is to change personal homepage from:

```
http://xxx-lab.engr.xxx.xxxx.edu/me/index.htm
```

to

```
http://xxx-lab.engr.xxx.xxxx.edu/~me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much information about the webserver you are using...

If you are using Apache then you should look into url rewrite rules

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Yes I use Apache server. how can I make it? thanks